# How can I order the native django users in the django admin page based on creation time?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users, django-admin-filters

I wanted to know if there was a way of ordering the Django users on the django admin page based on creation time rather than alphabetical order. To be honest, it can be ordered by creation time or the id. But the order needs to be from latest users to the oldest.

I've done some research about ordering objects on the Admin page. I saw one source mentioning date hierarchy. Problem is I don't know the specific field to which the Django User can be ordered by.

Do you have any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering This is what you need

Comment: @karthikr hey! that is the same source I ran into earlier, but problem is which native django user field should I order by? ID? also, put yout solution in the answer section so that I may accept your answer and upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
ordering = ['-date_joined']
```

You can order by any field the model gives you. 
Since you didn't specify the UserModel you are using, I guess you are talking about the BaseUser?
If so, you can order by:

- first_name
- last_name
- id
- email
- date_joined
- username
- [is_staff] # bool
- [is_active] # bool

Comment: ups, two years late :)

Comment: Ahaha this was back when I first started with Django, had no prior experience with MVC frameworks or programming! I've come a long way since!